# Definite integral (mixture of functions)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have problem with this integral and I generally don't know how to approach it:
$$\int_{-2}^2 (x^4+4x+\cos(x))\cdot \arctan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)dx$$
I know that I probably have to make some substitution, but really don't know which.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

For even function $f(x)$, $$\int_{-a}^af(x)dx=2\int_0^af(x)dx$$

For odd  $$\int_{-a}^af(x)dx=0$$

$$(-x)=x^4,\cos(-x)=\cos x,\arctan\left(-\dfrac x2\right)=-\arctan\dfrac x2$$

$\implies$ if $\displaystyle g(x)=\left(x^4+4\cos x\right)\arctan\frac x2,g(-x)=-g(x)$

If $\displaystyle h(x)=x\cdot\arctan\dfrac x2,h(-x)=h(x)$

So, the given integral reduces to $$2\int_0^24x\cdot\arctan\dfrac x2 dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Using lab bhattacharjee's result. The integral can be solven by using integration by parts.
Let
\begin{align}
u=\arctan\frac{x}{2}\qquad\rightarrow\qquad du=\frac{2\,dx}{x^2+4}\qquad\text{and}\qquad dv=x\,dx\qquad\rightarrow\qquad v=\frac{1}{2}x^2
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
8\int_0^2x\arctan\frac {x}{2}\, dx&=\left.4x^2\arctan\frac{x}{2}\right|_0^2-8\int_0^2 \frac{x^2}{x^2+4}\,dx\\
&=4\pi-8\int_0^2 \frac{x^2+4-4}{x^2+4}\,dx\\
&=4\pi-8\int_0^2 \,dx+16\int_0^2 \frac{2}{x^2+4}\,dx\\
&=4\pi-16+16\, \left.\arctan\frac{x}{2}\right|_0^2\\
&=4\pi-16+4\pi\\
&=8\pi-16
\end{align}